# Kusto query for time difference

Tags: kql

If have a question about the kusto query language. When I query for a certain custom event (messages), I get a list of these events. Each message belongs to a certain conversation. I would like see the duration of each conversation.

To put it simple, if this is my sample data:

```
Timestamp          ConversationID
8-5-2020 12:45:37  9mCksoeRrG1KbHoRIWWq-h    
8-5-2020 12:45:39  9mCksoeRrG1KbHoRIWWq-h    
8-5-2020 13:29:12  5noGScSZcJZqgzmVDMWZ-h   
8-5-2020 13:29:14  5noGScSZcJZqgzmVDMWZ-h  
8-5-2020 13:29:17  5noGScSZcJZqgzmVDMWZ-h    
8-5-2020 13:29:23  5noGScSZcJZqgzmVDMWZ-h
```

I would like to see this:

```
ConversationID          Duration  
9mCksoeRrG1KbHoRIWWq-h  2(seconds?)   
5noGScSZcJZqgzmVDMWZ-h  11(seconds?)
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!
Regards, 
Tom

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, ConversationID:string)
[
    datetime(8-5-2020 12:45:37), '9mCksoeRrG1KbHoRIWWq-h',    
    datetime(8-5-2020 12:45:39), '9mCksoeRrG1KbHoRIWWq-h',    
    datetime(8-5-2020 13:29:12), '5noGScSZcJZqgzmVDMWZ-h',   
    datetime(8-5-2020 13:29:14), '5noGScSZcJZqgzmVDMWZ-h',  
    datetime(8-5-2020 13:29:17), '5noGScSZcJZqgzmVDMWZ-h',    
    datetime(8-5-2020 13:29:23), '5noGScSZcJZqgzmVDMWZ-h',   
]
| summarize duration = max(Timestamp) - min(Timestamp) by ConversationID
```

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the solution!