# Kusto query for time difference between records

Tags: kql

I'm looking for a way to query the time difference (in seconds) between two records grouped by operation id.
When given this sample data:

```
datatable(timestamp:datetime, operation_id:string)
[
    datetime(15-7-2021 12:45:37), 'abc',    
    datetime(15-7-2021 12:45:39), 'abc',    
    datetime(15-7-2021 13:29:12), 'def',   
    datetime(15-7-2021 13:29:14), 'def',  
    datetime(15-7-2021 13:29:17), 'def',    
    datetime(15-7-2021 13:29:23), 'def',   
]
```

The expected output would be:

| operation_id | diff |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 2 |
| def | 2 |
| def | 3 |
| def | 6 |

Is this possible?

P.s. it's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61680990/kusto-query-for-time-difference) but I do not want the difference between the min and max but for each record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can order the table and then use the `prev()` function:

```
datatable(ts:datetime, op_id:string)
[
    datetime(07-15-2021 12:45:37), 'abc',
    datetime(07-15-2021 12:45:39), 'abc',
    datetime(07-15-2021 13:29:12), 'def',
    datetime(07-15-2021 13:29:14), 'def',
    datetime(07-15-2021 13:29:17), 'def',
    datetime(07-15-2021 13:29:23), 'def',
]
| order by op_id asc, ts asc
| extend prev_ts = prev(ts), prev_op_id = prev(op_id)
| project op_id, diff = case(prev_op_id == op_id, (ts - prev_ts)/1s, double(null))
| where isnotnull(diff)
```

| op_id | diff |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 2 |
| def | 2 |
| def | 3 |
| def | 6 |

Comment: Wow, that's a fast answer! Thanks!